# I have a form and I want to create a button on another activity when the form is submitted

Tags: java, android, firebase

The form that I made has 2 fields, a name and a point value. When the form is submitted there are 2 fields that are stored in the cloud firestore in the realtime database. When the form is submitted I want the text inside the button to be the text field and I want the button's value to be the number. How would I do this. Something I mean by this would be :

```
       String point = editTextPoint.get.getText().toString().trim();
        String name= editTextName.get.getText().toString().trim();
          form.onSubmit{
         createbutton();
         button.val = point
         button text = name
       }
```

I know that this code doesn't make sense but this is just an example of what I want. Could you guys offer a possible solution?

Comment: Please specify what you meant by value and text. Do you want to have a combined name of the button?

Comment: By value I mean there are numbers that will be assigned and also there is a text field in a form that generates the button